# Play Framework 2.5 with Server Side Events

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to make a simple tic-tac-toe online multiplayer game in Play Framework in Java (but I can read Scala too) and I need to notify one client when the other client has made a move - has inserted a new database entry. The frontend uses HTML and JS.

Do I use WebSockets or Server Sent Events for this and how?

Thanks a lot guys, the Play framework documentation for both is still not updated and it's a well known issue https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5057 as well.

**EDIT:** The main question here is really how to do it?

Comment: So what's your question? If your question is SSE vs WS, as you described you only need to send from the server to the client, then use SSE, but if you need information flow on both ways you may use WS.

Comment: My question is which one do I use. The connection is both ways - it is between two clients and a server. I don't need constant connection as it's a turn-based game, so SSE is sufficient; but WS is better. Should I still use SSE or use WebSockets and, of course, why?

Comment: SSE does not work both ways.... If you need two way communication then use WebSockets.

Comment: If you think that WS is better (by your own criteria and NEEDS ), than you already answered you own question.

Comment: Yeah but I can use SSE and HTTP POST. As said, it's a turn-based game and turns usually last, up to a minute. So is having a WS here an overkill? Have in mind there might be up to 5k active games at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally for a game I would establish a Web Socket connection over a SSE.

- Fast data transfers
- A two way stream of message, where SSE would require the client to send ajax requests and listen to SSE where WS all sits in one place.
- Allows you to establish when one of the 2 clients looses connections, thus pausing or notifying the other player.

Resource you can use to Implement this:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets

**Edit:** Latest version https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets

Comment: This is the exact documentation I said was deprecated and outdated.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets - Latest.

It uses sinks and flows which is the functional (akka http) way of approaching it

Comment: Hey I didn't see the documentation for 2.6.x at all - they finally did it right. For anyone looking for Java code: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets